# Keeping trailing 0's when using fast enumeration on an array of floats

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an `NSMutableArray` that contains floats. I first wrap the float in an `NSNumber` so that it can be added to the array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.10f];
[array addObject:num];
```

I use fast enumeration to show them to the user (I will use `NSLog` here):

```
for (NSString *aString in array) {
        NSLog(@"Value: %@", aString);
    }
```

However, this code will print `Value: 5.1`, but I'd like for it to print in a currency format showing `Value: 5.10`. It doesn't matter how it is stored, just how it is displayed. I need it stored as a float rather than a string so I can do calculations with the floats in the array.

Comment: Why are you declaring `aString` as an `NSString` in your `for` loop? The array contains `NSNumber` instances, not `NSString` instances.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah yes, Objective-C, it all comes back to me now... :) where you can declare something with the wrong type and get away with it... I miss those days... sniff...

Comment: @matt I checked out the documentation for NSNumberFormatter and it was what I was looking for, thanks. I am having trouble listing out the array items though, as updated in the original question, and have been trying to work it out with different approaches since you commented.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm new and it was just a mistake; thanks for pointing that out and I fixed it in my code and the new edit.

Comment: @JohnL As matt stated, do not redo this question. Accept the answer below and post a new question with relevant code if needed.

Comment: @matt My original question is answered, but I did not want to make a second consecutive question when it was closely tied with my original question. If that's the way it should be done on this site, however, then that's the way I'll do it. Regarding `NSLog`: That _is_ what I started with before applying it to UI. Lying about it would be silly and accusations sillier.

Comment: “If that's the way it should be done on this site” Yes, that’s the idea I was attempting to inculcate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for `NSNumberFormatter`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter?language=objc

Once it's set up to format numbers the way you want, you can just use its `stringFromNumber:` method to produce a nicely formatted string. If your display is happening in the UI rather than in code via `NSLog`, you can actually set up your formatter entirely in Interface Builder.

Alternatively, you can use a format string:

```
NSLog(@"%.2f", num.floatValue);
```

Comment: Thank you, could you elaborate on setting up the formatter in Interface Builder with a text view? I don't see the option.

Comment: @JohnL You need to use a text field rather than a text view. Drag a number formatter onto the text field and it will attach. At that point you can then configure the formatter in the Attributes Inspector.